# When overriding WebViewPage how do I distinguish pages from partials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm overriding `System.Web.Mvc.WebPageView<T>` where I'm doing some processing applicable to all pages, thus:

```
public abstract class AppViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    protected override void InitializePage()
    {
        DoStuff();
        base.InitializePage();
    }
}
```

however I see InitializePage() is invoked multiple times for a single page hit, once for the page view itself and once each for every contained partial and containing layout. How can I distinguish these different contexts so that I can perform my operation only once?

Comment: and how you use this class??

Comment: you have Layout property in this type you can check its Layout property with if statement like : ``if(this.Layout == null)``

Comment: The class is referenced in the web.config setting `<pages pageBaseType="AppViewPage">`. I find `this.Layout` is always `null`.